# execute Spark jobs, with Livy, using `--master yarn-cluster` without making systemwide changes

Tags: apache-spark, livy

I'd like to execute a Spark job, via an HTTP call from outside the cluster using [Livy](http://livy.io/), where the Spark jar already exists in HDFS.

I'm able to `spark-submit` the job from shell on the cluster nodes, e.g.:

```
spark-submit --class io.woolford.Main --master yarn-cluster hdfs://hadoop01:8020/path/to/spark-job.jar
```

Note that the `--master yarn-cluster` is necessary to access HDFS where the jar resides.

I'm also able to submit commands, via Livy, using `curl`. For example, this request:

```
curl -X POST --data '{"file": "/path/to/spark-job.jar", "className": "io.woolford.Main"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" hadoop01:8998/batches
```

... executes the following command on the cluster:

```
spark-submit --class io.woolford.Main hdfs://hadoop01:8020/path/to/spark-job.jar
```

This is the same as the command that works, minus the `--master yarn-cluster` params. This was verified by tailing `/var/log/livy/livy-livy-server.out`.

So, I just need to modify the `curl` command to include `--master yarn-cluster` when it's executed by Livy. At first glance, it seems like this should be possible by adding arguments to the JSON dictionary. Unfortunately, these aren't passed through.

Does anyone know how to pass `--master yarn-cluster` to Livy so that jobs are executed on YARN without making [systemwide changes](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/d/msg/livy-user/8_-rPW0aD38/80ZFfHVfNgAJ)?

Answer (score 0):

I recently tried something similar as your question. I need to send a HTTP request to Livy's API, while Livy is already installed in a cluster (YARN), and then I want to let Livy start a Spark job.

My command to call Livy did not include `--master yarn-cluster`, but that seems to work for me. Maybe you can try to put your JAR file in local in stead of in a cluster?

Answer (score 0):

spark.master = yarn-cluster

set it in the spark conf, for me:/etc/spark2/conf/spark-defaults.conf